# Three dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, image, vector

I am making a three dimensional array for image manipulation - X and Y dimensions and then a third dimension because each pixel has not one value but (bitsPerPixel/8) values.

I am frankly not very well versed in C++ but the API for the camera is strictly C++ and so I want to check up with somebody more skilled before I set out and ask "is this right?":

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> mask(m_nSizeX, vector<vector<int>>(m_nSizeY, vector<int>(m_nBitsPerPixel / 8)));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have C++11 support, then yes.

If not, you need some extra spaces in your templates:

```
vector<vector<vector<int> > >
```

instead of

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>>
```

and so on...

Although I personally wouldn't use a `vector` for the last value, but rather a structure.

Comment: I remember I read somewhere that the spaces are "recommended" rather than "needed", but I can be wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I suspect I DO have C++11 support (I work in Visual Studio 2010) but I'll add the spaces in to be certain. The Struct idea might be useful once I know the actual bit-size of the image but currently it's up in the air whether it'll be 8-bit monochrome or 24 bit color.

Comment: Yay it not only compiles, it works - I have bit-level access to the image. Slow, slow, bit-level access. I'll probably end up doing it with a direct memory-access method later because the vector-based approach is entirely too slow compared to what happened earlier, but it works and I have access. Thank you.

Comment: @MrLister The spaces are needed in pre-C++11, because of the maximum munch rule.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use nested vectors at all.  I'd use a single `std::vector<Pixel>`, converting the `x` and `y` into a single index when needed.  And like you, I wouldn't use a vector for the bits in the pixel; I'd use a built-in integral type if possible (it's possible up to 64 bits), otherwise a C style array wrapped in a struct.

Comment: Mm. The advantage of doing it in multiple dimensions is that when I do image manipulation (e.g. blur the image by averaging the pixel color values with the color values next to it) the programming is much simplified by being able to refer to (x+1) and (y+1) instead of (x+1) and (x+(m_nSizeX)) which would be the nearest neighbor in the Y dimension. That said? Once I'm done with the proof-of-concept stage and start optimizing for speed and memory access, I will probably do just that.

Answer (score 0):

well yes the definition is right. As for the parameters I can't say, since I can't see your headers

as a  general practice I always use the namespace name before the class
so I never do:

```
using namespace std;
vector<int> numbers;

but instead

std::vector<int> numbers
```

This is just for me easier to read and follow the errors
Also if you intend to pass this 3D vector around, then you might need to also pass to define an allocator for the vector. but this is dependant on what you want to do

Comment: This is actually what I do - I removed the six (6!) std:: for clarity - the line was long enough even without them.